# JPA @OneTomany @ManyToOne mutliple instances

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

For a tournament manager project, I have a tournament class which contains a list for Rounds.
For treatment purpose, I have the reverse reference, the round knows its tournament.

So I defined @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relations

```
class Tournament
{
@OneToMany (mappedBy="tournament")
private List<Round> mRounds;
}
```

```
class Round
{
@ManyToOne
private Tournament tournament;
}
```

But the tournament is instanciated twice. The parent tournament is not the same which is contained by the Round instance (even if the Id is the same). How can I setup the JPA relationships to ensure that the same instance is used.

Comment: Add some code .

Comment: Do you load entities in a @Trasanctional Context ?

Comment: Please override equals() and hashCode() method.

Comment: I'm here because I wanted to ask exactly the same question. If (in this example) the Tournament is read from the database (in my case using a Spring boot JPA repo) and you print the instance's hashcode, it differs from what you get if you print myTournament.mRounds.get(0).tournament. I'd expect them to be the same instance, otherwise you can only "refer back" for read operations.

Answer (score 0):

Because the OneToMany does not have fetch=FetchType.EAGER, the Round instance can be loaded later, using a different EntityManager, and that creates a different instance of Tournament in the Round instance.

So the trick is to EAGER fetch everything (using @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) when there are multiple lists), or at least everything within the aggregate.